# MongoServerError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type binData instead

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bindata

so I have field "status" and "timestamp" in my mongodb document, and these fields have this custom type: TransactionRequestStatus and TransactionRequestTimestamp respectively.

```
type TransactionRequestStatus = {
    isApproved: boolean,
    isRejected: boolean,
    isDeleted: boolean,
}
type TransactionRequestTimestamp = {
    resolved?: Date,
    created?: Date,
    deleted?: Date
}
```

I want to update the status field by running this on nodejs environment.

```
const timestamp = {
    resolved: Date,
    created: Date,
    deleted: Date
}
const status = {
    isApproved: true,
    isRejected: false,
    isDeleted: false,
}
const document = {status, timestamp}
const updateResponse = await collection.updateOne(query, {$set: document});
```

but this returns this error instead:

```
{
  error: MongoServerError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type binData instead. For example: {$mod: {<field>: ...}} not {$set: BinData(0, )}
      at /var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/update.js:70:33
      at /var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/command.js:84:64
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    index: 0,
    code: 9,
    [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
  },
  message: 'internal server error at database update'
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.